# How to display firebase backend data in mapbox gl

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapbox, mapbox-gl

How can I import firebase data to the gl system for display in an html file?

I'm working from this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/heatmap/. I don't know what to put for map.addSource and data. Thanks for any advice.

Here is some code from leaflet html file that I want to adapt for gl:

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: [key],
authDomain: "[domain name]",
databaseURL: "[url]",
storageBucket: "bitebytes-4d211.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "[id]"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

defaultDatabase = firebase.database();
var openedOnce = false
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user && !openedOnce) {
openedOnce = true
var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
var uid = user.uid;
var reportsRef = firebase.database().ref('reports/');
reportsRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
console.log('reports child_added');
addPoint(data.val());
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs to be in valid GeoJSON format from firebase, then this json is added like you would add any other geojson source using mapbox examples. There are far too many ways to structure your firebase data to go into detail here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got some help and figured it out, but if anyone has a link to an example online, that would be helpful as a reference (I don't know enough about my code to generalize it so I can make it public).